# How to make closed eyes and mouth open

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

I'm a beginner of blender. I have a human model, and my goal is to let the model make expressions, so I have to make its mouth and eyes open. However, the model is totally closed, just like in the first two pictures. I want to achieve the result in the third and fourth picture, where as you can see there are new edges added in the eyes and the mouth.

I want to know what procedures should I do to achieve my goal. Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you select and edge and press V it will rip it and you'll be able to open the mesh. Another solution would be to recreate the topology to have something cleaner (see retopology)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I tried the first method and it works. I want to know if I should use the knife to cut the mouth and face to make it look better.

Comment: the Knife tool allows to add edges, how do you want to use it?

Comment: 'cause the edges are not in the same line, I want it open more naturally

Comment: ah yes sure you can cut along the mouth line then rip. But again, if you want a clean topology you need to retopologize, it all depends on the final goal, a bad topology can be ok, depending on what you want to do

Comment: Thanks! I'll learn about the retopology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut with the knife along the line that you want to cut then use <kbd>V</kbd> to rip:

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you!